# Click and/or focus outside & -webkit-tap-highlight-color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working code sample [here](http://jsbin.com/ugilev).

Note: *Above **only** tested in Firefox 13.0.1, iPad (non-retina) and Chrome 20.0.x.*

Here's the relevant code:

```
var $outside = $(document)
    .add($('html'))
    .add($(':not[' + data.target + ']'));

$outside.on('focusin.goober click.goober', function(e) {

    if ($(e.target).closest(data.target).length === 0) {

        $outside.off('.goober');

        data.divs.hide(); // Collection of sub menu divs.

    } else {

        return true;

    }

}).css('-webkit-tap-highlight-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'); // Hide tap highlight color via Mobile Safari.
```

**I'm looking for feedback on two issues:**

1. Clicking and/or focusing outside: Where you see

   ```
   var $outside = $(document).add($('html')).add($(':not[' + data.target + ']'));
   ```

   that's where I check for focusin/click events **outside** the target menu. I have my reservations about applying event handlers to everything just to detect an outside focus/click. Without [using a plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/), is there a better way to detect focus/click outside of a target element? Could this code be improved?
2. I'm also concerned about how `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` behaves when tapping outside via iPad. As a quick monkey patch, I've added

   ```
   .css('-webkit-tap-highlight-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)')
   ```

   but I don't yet see that as the perfect solution.

**In regards to #2 above:**

I wonder if I should add a CSS class to the `<html>` element, something like "`disable-highlight`", and have in my CSS

```
.disable-highlight * { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
```

and have JS add the class when the menu is being interacted with (and remove it when its not)? I rarely use `*` selector in my CSS these days, but as a temporary way to hide the tap/click highlight, maybe that's not a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several days of hard work, I think that I've found the answers to my questions.

1. The best element I've found to check for outside click/focus is `$(document)`.

   Caveat: When on iPad, the event needs to be `touchstart`, not `click`.

   I've got a question [going here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406285/determine-and-bind-click-or-touch-event), but here's the "trick" I'm using currently:

   ```
   var foo = (('ontouchstart' in window) || (window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch)) ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
   ```

   I'm using [this technique here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9440580/922323) to handle `focus`/`click`. Essentially, when there's keyboard tab focus, I call `click` and within that event handler, I call my code to check for outside `focus`/`click`/`touch`.
2. The idea I had to add a CSS class to `<html>` works pretty good. When the event handlers are setup to listen for `focus`/`click`/`touch` outside, I add the class. Once there's been `focus`/`click`/`touch` on the outside, I remove the class.

   My CSS looks like so:

   ```
   html.mw-outside * { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
   ```

   It kinda feels a little hacky, though.

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but [here's a real-world jQuery plugin I wrote (a few years back) that uses this technique](https://github.com/mhulse/jquery-megawhale); also, [here's more recent JS code I use to detect of touch is supported](https://gist.github.com/mhulse/4704893#file-no-x-js-L9-L14). (thanks for edit @Jamal)